# yii2 file upload not working

Tags: file-upload, yii2

I have followed the following guide https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-file-upload.md but no file is being uploaded. below is my configuration

**_form**

This is in a for loop so i can get an array of different records.

```
<?= $form->field(new UploadForm , "[$count]file")->fileInput()->label(false) ?>
```

**view**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>...
```

**controller**

```
if(isset(Yii::$app->request->post()['Factsheets'])){

                for($i=0 ; $i < count(Yii::$app->request->post()['Factsheets']); $i++) {
                    //Yii::error(print_r(Yii::$app->request->post()['Factsheets'][$i],true));

                    if(!empty(Yii::$app->request->post()['UploadForm'][$i]['file'])){
                        $file = new UploadForm();
                        $file->file = UploadedFile::getInstance(Yii::$app->request->post()['UploadForm'][$i], 'file');

                        if ($file->file && $file->validate()) {
                            $file->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $file->file->baseName . '.' . $file->file->extension);
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
```

**post log**

```
[Factsheets] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type] => image
                [factsheet_id] => 1185
                [path] => ../public/filespool/2/289/Pelotas_Reprocessing.jpg
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [type] => tech_paper
                [factsheet_id] => 1433
                [path] => ?basin=pelotas
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [type] => factsheet
                [factsheet_id] => 1844
                [path] => ../public/filespool/2/289/Pelotas_Reprocessing.pdf
            )

    )

[UploadForm] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => 
            )

    )
```

I have noticed the following in the post log now. how do i construct it?

```
$_FILES = [
    'UploadForm' => [
        'name' => [
            0 => [
                'file' => 'Destin_Dome.jpg'
            ]
            1 => [
                'file' => ''
            ]
            2 => [
                'file' => 'Pelotas_Reprocessing.pdf'
            ]
        ]
        'type' => [
            0 => [
                'file' => 'image/jpeg'
            ]
            1 => [
                'file' => ''
            ]
            2 => [
                'file' => ''
            ]
        ]
        'tmp_name' => [
            0 => [
                'file' => '/tmp/phpoPgbJ9'
            ]
            1 => [
                'file' => ''
            ]
            2 => [
                'file' => ''
            ]
        ]
        'error' => [
            0 => [
                'file' => 0
            ]
            1 => [
                'file' => 4
            ]
            2 => [
                'file' => 1
            ]
        ]
        'size' => [
            0 => [
                'file' => 1129373
            ]
            1 => [
                'file' => 0
            ]
            2 => [
                'file' => 0
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

It seems like it is failing validation however i was able to make a copy like:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['UploadForm']['tmp_name']['file'])){
                        copy($_FILES['UploadForm']['tmp_name']['file'],"/tmp/".$_FILES['UploadForm']['name']['file']);
}
```

fileUpload model

```
public $file;
    public $image;
    public $factsheet;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['file'], 'file','maxFiles' => 10],
            [['image'], 'file','extensions' => 'gif, jpg'],
            [['factsheet'], 'file','checkExtensionByMimeType' => false,'extensions' => 'pdf'],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but I think the problem is in your controller: your model rules are for multiple file upload and your form field too, but in the controller you set `$model->file` as a single `UploadedFile` instance. That is why your validation does not work. I can't give your advice (to change controller or model rule) because I do not clearly understand what are you doing here. It looks like you are creating multiple models from a single file upload field...

Comment: i am trying to upload multiple files